# Prevent access to /index (default Controller action)

Tags: php, laravel, routes

My `routes.php` looks like this:

```
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

The default root action is `getIndex()`. Typing the address `[DOMAIN NAME]/index` though, returns the start page as well. How do I prevent this? I want the start page to only be accessible when going to the root URI of my project (`/`).

Comment: You are you using RESTful Resource Controllers , you should change it to Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

There's a reason I want a controller that takes care of all my routes :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using RESTful Resource Controllers, replace it with,

```
 Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');
```

**OTHER OPTIONS**

/ refers to index method in the controller by default, you could make index refer to another method which creates the view you want like.

```
   Route::get('index', 'SomeController@someMethod');
```

in your route.php file

If you want the page to show a 404 you can use in your SomeController@someMethod

```
public function someMethod()
{
   App::abort(404)
 }
```

Or without the use of a method

```
 Route::get('index', function() { 
   App::abort(404) 
 })
```

Comment: Sure, but I want `/index` to return a 404 error, because it's  not supposed to be an address the user can access

Comment: you can redirect in SomeController@someMethod to yourpage.com/404

Comment: What did you have in mind? If you want two different methods you have to make 2 different methods, and two differen route rules to point to the methods.

Comment: No, I just want `/` to be a valid path to the `root`, and `/index` to not be. I want a solution where Laravel resorts to 404 because it can't find a method called `index`

Comment: Route::get('index', function()
{
    App::abort(404)
}); in your route file

Comment: Your solution requires one to blacklist routes, that's not what I want. Would this require me to make a route for every path I **don't** want my user to access? Doesn't really make sense.

Comment: you could add a custom rule like   Route::get('{any}', function()
{
    App::abort(404);
}); this will show a 404 on every not defined route. so if you dont define the index route it will throw 404, only defined routes will run a method. make sure you post it at the bottom of your route

Answer (score 0):

Like pointed out in the comments, you need to blacklist the `/index` route. **But only that one!** You don't need to blacklist *every* route you don't want your users to see, because Laravel will handle that for every route that is not defined. But `index` is a **special case**, because you have to name the default route *some* name, don't you?

So long talk, short meaning: Rest assured, you will *only* have to blacklist each `index` route, if it is that important to you.